# Sort objects by values in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, treeset

I have an Hashmap with some activity (key) and date (values), and i want to display them order by values, like the first date is in first, the second is in the second place ... With this code :

```
public void afficheRS(HashMap<Activity, monCalendrier> edt) {
        SortedSet<monCalendrier> values = new TreeSet<>(edt.values());
        System.out.println(values);
        for(Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> entry : edt.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("| " + entry.getKey() + "\n    " + entry.getValue() +  " |" );

        }
    }
```

But now, i only display values (by SortedSet) in order, but when i use :

```
for(Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> entry : edt.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("| " + entry.getKey() + "\n    " + entry.getValue() +  " |" );

            }
```

This display all my activies (like a want) but not order by values (and it's normal because that i want to do but i don't know what to do)

when i call afficheRS that display this (for example, it's a random generator) :

```
    [6:27 8/11/2019, 13:12 8/11/2019, 20:16 8/11/2019] 
| Go to school(durée : 30 minutes) 13:12 8/11/2019 | 
| Homework (durée : 60 minutes) 20:16 8/11/2019 | 
| Take a coffe (durée : 10 minutes) 6:27 8/11/2019 |
```

And i want

```
     [6:27 8/11/2019, 13:12 8/11/2019, 20:16 8/11/2019] 
| Take a coffe (durée : 10 minutes) 6:27 8/11/2019 |
| Go to school(durée : 30 minutes) 13:12 8/11/2019 | 
| Homework (durée : 60 minutes) 20:16 8/11/2019 |
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I think you could use Comparable as described here https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap-sort

Comment: You are looping over the original, unsored Map, not the sorted TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

`SortedSet<monCalendrier> values = new TreeSet<>(edt.values());` Here you are putting the values in a `new SortedSet` object to sort it and your map actually doesn't get sorted by values. So when next time when you call `etd.entrySet()` it returns the unsorted set of entries.

Either you may choose to create a `TreeSet` of sorted entries itself and then print the key-value pair by iterating. Or You may try something like following with Java 8 stream and functions.

```
  LinkedHashMap edt = edt
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
          .collect(
            toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
                LinkedHashMap::new));;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Comparator object and then use Collections.sort method to sort the hashmap based on a particular type of class values. Please refer this article for a detailed example. https://www.java67.com/2015/01/how-to-sort-hashmap-in-java-based-on.html

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
public void afficheRS(HashMap<Activity, monCalendrier> edt) {
        HashMap<Activity, monCalendrier> =  sortByValue(edt);
        for(Map.Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> entry : edt.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("| " + entry.getKey() + "\n    " + entry.getValue() +  " |" );

        }
}

public static HashMap<Activity, monCalendrier> sortByValue(HashMap<Activity, monCalendrier> hm) 
    { 
        // Create a list from elements of HashMap 
        List<Map.Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> > list = 
               new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> >(hm.entrySet()); 

        // Sort the list 
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> >() { 
            public int compare(Map.Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> o1,  
                               Map.Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> o2) 
            { 
                return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue()); 
            } 
        }); 

        // put data from sorted list to hashmap  
        HashMap<Activity, monCalendrier> temp = new LinkedHashMap<Activity, monCalendrier>(); 
        for (Map.Entry<Activity, monCalendrier> aa : list) { 
            temp.put(aa.getKey(), aa.getValue()); 
        } 
        return temp; 
    }
```